# RabbitMQ connection closed exception

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 218, in process_data_events
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed

```
def main():
print('zmq', zmq.zmq_version(), zmq.pyzmq_version())
zctx = zmq.Context()
socket_rep = zctx.socket(zmq.REP)
socket_rep.bind('tcp://*:'+str(dragon_pb2.tcpport.Value('stage1_server_request_storage')))

RabbitReceiver(host='localhost', on_receive_callback=handle_massage, exchange_name='exchange1', queue_name='name1')

while True:
    try:
        request = socket_rep.recv_json()
        status, result = get_records(request)
        if result is None:
            result = {}
        # print result
        socket_rep.send_multipart([status, blosc.compress(json.dumps(result), 9)])

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Buy")
        sys.exit()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()


class RabbitReceiver(AbstractReceiver):
    def __init__(self, on_receive_callback, host, exchange_name, queue_name):
        AbstractReceiver.__init__(self, host=host, on_receive_callback=on_receive_callback)
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=AbstractReceiver.host))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name,
                                 type='fanout')

        channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)

        channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange_name,
                           queue=queue_name)
        channel.basic_consume(self.on_message_receive,
                      queue=queue_name)

        channel.start_consuming()

    def on_message_receive(self, channel, method, header, body):
        AbstractReceiver.on_message_receive(self, body)
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

I know that code after the creation of RabbitReceiver probably wouldn't be executed because start_consuming is blocking. But right now I'm not worried about that.
I want to know why it's giving me this error?
Probably I've missed something...

Comment: After first message arrived.

Comment: Did you check the rabbitmq log file for any clue ?